# Database population with django models, module not found error

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I am just getting started with the Django framework through the book "The Definitive Guide to Django." I used `psycopg2` to write my SQL insert statements (Postgres) through a script named `scrape.py`. I wanted to switch to using the Django models, however, I get an `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured` error when I try to run `from models import articles`. I first used

```py
import os
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'CannaMed.settings'
```

But got the error

```
  File "/home/ian/CannaMed/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 127, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "/home/ian/CannaMed/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 260, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "/home/ian/CannaMed/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 137, in check_apps_ready
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/home/ian/CannaMed/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 87, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/home/ian/CannaMed/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 74, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/home/ian/CannaMed/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 183, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'CannaMed'
```

I then added

```
import django 
django.setup()
```

and got the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scrape.py", line 2, in <module>
    django.setup()
  File "/home/ian/CannaMed/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
    configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
  File "/home/ian/CannaMed/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 87, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/home/ian/CannaMed/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 67, in _setup
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting LOGGING_CONFIG, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

Lastly I just went into the interactive shell and ran `import CannaMed.settings' and it gave me a ModuleNotFoundError.

My directory tree, settings.py, and sys.path are provided below.

Tree:

```
.
├── CannaMed
│   ├── asgi.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── close.py
├── dataanalysis.py
├── geckodriver.log
├── journalfeed
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── geckodriver.log
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   │   ├── 0002_users_id_alter_users_email_alter_users_visits.py
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── nlp.py
│   ├── scrape.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   └── views.py
├── manage.py
└── templates
    └── CannaMed
        └── index.html
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'journalfeed',
]
```

sys.path

```
['', '/usr/lib/python38.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.8', '/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload', '/home/ian/CannaMed/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages']
```

Comment: Try writing custom management command instead

Comment: @IainShelvington some explanation and an example would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The official docs give a pretty good explanation and some examples https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/custom-management-commands/. A custom management command is ideal for creating stand-alone scripts that need access to Django

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `CannaMed` into INSTALLED_APPS

Comment: Same error, No module `CannaMed`. Ran after running `python3 manage.py check`.